# ASP.NET validation: gathering information from client-side validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, client-side-validation

I'd like to implement ajax message box that will gather information from validators on a page when client-side validation fires. 
Like: I have left some text fields blank then press submit button and appropriate RequiredFieldValidators show messages. I would like my message box shows those messages too. I am looking for appropriate way to hook on validators JS event or something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this fit the bill?

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/308/validationsummary/

Comment: Yeah, I looked at validatonSummary control. As it gathers validation messages from validaton control I can try to find out how can I hook on this control's JS.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by adding an event handler?

Comment: I would like to display those messages in my message box. So all I'd like to do it to be able to retrieve those client-side messages and process them.

Answer (score 1):

What about [Using jQuery with the ASP.NET CustomValidator Control](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=299)?